# Sed replace value with variable

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have a variable in a config, which I would like to replace with a value.

```
ROOT="rROOT"
```

I would like to replace that with

```
ROOT="$root"
```

So with the value of $root (Important are the quotation marks).

So far I have tried it that way

```
sed -i s/'ROOT=rROOT'/'ROOT="$root"'/g $directory/settings.conf
```

The result is that

```
ROOT="$root"
```

But this is stored in the variable $root (It is always a path)

```
root: /
```

How can I replace rROOT with the value of $root?

Sed Version: (GNU sed) 4.2.2

Comment: See: [Difference between single and double quotes in bash](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6697753/3776858)

Comment: Escape the dollar sign. Something like this: ```\$```.

Answer (score 5):

Ok, don't like to ruin my scripts for testing:

```
cat tageslog.sh | sed "s/alt=185094/alt=\${root}/g"
```

Use double quotes, but mask the dollar sign, so it doesn't get lost and root interpreted while calling sed.

Use ${root} instead of "$root".

```
sed "s/ROOT=.rRoot./ROOT=\${root}/g" $directory/settings.conf
```

if this works, use the -i switch:

```
sed -i "s/ROOT=.rRoot./ROOT=\${root}/g" $directory/settings.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

You have different problems:

- Testing with `echo`
  I think you tested your command with
  `echo ROOT="rROOT" | sed s/'ROOT=rROOT'/'ROOT="$root"'/g`
  The double quotes won't appear in the output of the echo, so you will end up with a command working for `ROOT=rROOT`.
  When the inputfile has qouble quotes, you do not have to insert them.
  Testing with the double quotes is possible with
  `echo 'ROOT="rROOT"' | sed s/'ROOT=rROOT'/'ROOT="$root"'/g`
- Place the double quotes outside the single quotes;
  You can test this with `echo`:
  `echo 'Showing "$PWD" in double quotes is "'$PWD'"'`
  `echo 'With additional spaces the last part is " '$PWD' " '`
- Root vaiable has slashes that will confuse `sed`.
  The root variable is replaced before `sed` tries to understand the command.
  You can use another character, like `#`, in the `sed` command:
  `sed 's#before#after#'`

When your input has double quotes:

```
echo 'ROOT="rROOT"' | sed 's#ROOT="rROOT"#ROOT="'$root'"#g'
# or by remembering strings
echo 'ROOT="rROOT"' | sed -r 's#(ROOT=")rROOT(")#\1'$root'\2#g'
```

Input without double quotes

```
echo 'ROOT=rROOT' | sed 's#ROOT=rROOT#ROOT="'$root'"#g'
# or by remembering strings
echo 'ROOT=rROOT' | sed -r 's#(ROOT=)rROOT#\1"'$root'"#g'
```